# SQL-using if exist in matching two columns in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

im trying to use keywords like detergent, soap, dish etc to match two column in my sql table, if the keywords find match in two column, i want to have another column saying its a matched. i am planning to use the if exist but i do not know the proper syntax.

sample column:

```
Column1                Column2
-----------------------------------------------
detergent powder       all powder detergent
dish washing liquid    dish liquid for washing 
hand soap              hand liquid soap
```

Comment: What is your expcted result?

Comment: Where do you get the keywords to match on  from, is soap, dish etc a static list or taken from another table ?

Comment: expected result will be column 1 and column 2 plus another column saying its matched. if there is not match in two columns using the available keyword, then will not appear in the table. keywords are static, i make a list of keywords to be used.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `LIKE` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that checks if any of the 3 words appears in both columns.

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
 Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Col1 VARCHAR(100), 
 Col2 VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO Test (Col1, Col2) VALUES
('detergent powder', 'all powder detergent'),
('dish washing liquid', 'dish liquid for washing'),
('hand soap', 'hand liquid soap'),
('soap dish', 'detergent');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT  t.*
 , cast(
      case 
      when exists (
           select 1 
           from (values ('soap'),('detergent'),('dish')) s(search)
           join (values (Col1),(Col2)) c(col)
           on c.col like '%'+s.search+'%'
           group by s.search
           having count(*) = 2
     ) then 1 else 0 end as bit) as hasMatch
FROM Test t;
```

An `EXISTS` checks if there's at least 1 result from a query.
And the `HAVING` clause makes sure that 2 matches per search words are needed.

But it can also be done without that `GROUP BY` & `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT  t.*
 , cast(case when exists (
           select 1 
           from (values ('soap'),('detergent'),('dish')) s(search)
           where Col1 like '%'+s.search+'%'
             and Col2 like '%'+s.search+'%'
     ) then 1 else 0 end as bit) as hasMatch
FROM Test t;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/SEUC20284)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest solution to your question. The trick is in the "virtual" column, aliased as **Match**, that we create in the `select` statement. This column is computed using a `case` statement to see if the search term appears in both of the columns. Note we need to use the `like` statement with wildcard operators `%`.

```
create table Example (Column1 varchar(max), Column2 varchar(max));
insert into Example select 'detergent powder', 'all powder detergent';
insert into Example select 'dish washing liquid', 'dish liquid for washing' ;
insert into Example select 'hand soap', 'hand liquid soap';

declare @search varchar(20) = 'detergent';

select  Column1, 
        Column2, 
        case when Column1 like '%' + @search + '%' and 
                  Column2 like '%' + @search + '%' 
             then 'matched' 
             else 'not matched' end as [Match] 
from Example;
```

We could also create the **Match** column as a "real" column in the table and modify this script slightly to `update` that column based on the same criteria.

Comment: @roelcandare you're welcome. I'd appreciate an upvote and/or mark the question answered if this was helpful to you.